# Move file using Microsoft power automate in share point

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to move a newly uploaded file in sharepoint using power automate. I have used two connectors 1) When a file is created in a folder 2) Move File. I have used file identifier as dynamic content in the move file connector. When i tried i got this error.

**Error Message - Missing or mismatched field definition on the destination list for source field 'RequestType' type 'Text'. Source site template id 'GroupWebTemplateID', target site template id 'GroupWebTemplateID'. Total blocked root objects in this operation is [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Op7G.png).**

Am i using a wrong connector or wrong dynamic content

[image: Reference Image 1]

[image: Reference Image 2]

Comment: The error suggests that the destination is missing a metadata field/column. 

Did you create the RequestType field (type Single line of text) in the destination library/list?

Comment: I had a status column in the destination (Destination - Document Library in Share point). I created that status column after the creation of document library. Is it not working because of that?

Comment: No, I mean the other way around. The error suggests that in the source document library you have a column called RequestType. That column is not available in the destination document library? Is that correct, can you double check that?